# continuous scrolling with multiple PageView can possible?

Tags: flutter

The application I'm working on consists of three screens wrapped in a PageView: Screen A, Screen B, and Screen C. I can swipe from Screen A to reach Screen C. However, in Screen B, I have a widget structure with a Column that includes:

```
Direction buttons,
Expanded(
child: PageView(
children: [
Widget1,
Widget2
]
)
```

I can navigate to Screen C by dragging from outside the PageView widget on Screen B. However, what I want to achieve is being able to navigate to Screen C by swiping within the PageView widget on Screen B, but I can only see Widget2 because it is the last widget in the PageView.

My question is, is there a way to achieve continuous scrolling in the order of A - B (swiping the PageView to see Widget1 and Widget2) - C(after widget 2) by using a different widget instead of PageView?